# Understanding the compare command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, data-analysis, data-fitting, system-identification

I am very puzzled by the following Matlab observation.

In my problem I am trying to estimate an ARX/ARMAX model out of  discrete sampled input-output data. I am following Matlab's [guide to identify linear models in the command line](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/identify-linear-models-using-the-command-line.html) (using the System Identification toolbox)

- My dataset are 980 input-output pairs (experiments), with a sampling time of `Ts = 10` seconds (with 2 inputs, 1 output). I split the data `my_data` into two subsets of 490 experiments: `experimental` and `validation`.
- Running `delayest(my_data)` reveals that there is no delay in any of the inputs. Therefore `nk1=0` and `nk2=0`.
- Identifying an order with `selstruc` and `arxstruc` gives me a choice for the orders `na`,`nb1` and `nb2`.
- I set `opt=armaxOptions('InitialCondition','z')` to have zero initial condition for the system (I don't Matlab to treat it as an estimation variable).

With all of the above into consideration I run

```
my_model = arx(experimental,[6,[2,5],[0,0]],opt)
```

which gives the following model in the command line ([link on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1SJgaSt8)).

From the link above, if one scrolls down, we can see that the fit to `experimental` data is fairly well.

---

**And here comes my question**:

If I now want to validate the data with the `validation` subset, running a comparison with the [`compare`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/compare.html) command:

```
% the model had zero initial condition as well
opt=compareOptions('InitialCondition','z'); 
[~,fit_vector,~]=compare(validation,my_model,opt);
disp(num2str(cell2mat(fit_vector)))
```

and this is what is intriguing, now the displayed number is `-109.626 %` fit.

- Does anyone know the exact behaviour of this command, and why is there such a discrepancy between the fit when generating the model with `arx` (in the pastebin link above) and that of using the `compare` command?
- I find it very strange because even with different datasets `experimental` and `validation`, they both come from the same family of inputs (pulses of different duration and amplitude for input 1; input 2 is an exogenous input).

Comment: Maybe you are overfitting the data. Try lowering the model order and see if the performance on the validation data improves. Also, you selected stability focus. Try simulation focus. Please explain the difference between input 1 and input 2 in terms of the model structure. Input 1 has to be exogenous, too. This is a binary choice, the signal may be auto-regressive or exogenous. Maybe you can give a short description of your experimental setup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Setting the focus to 'simulation' did help in explaining the fit differences to `validation`. Now the fit from the new [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9JHBxcdd) is very bad as well.
Also, I will edit and try to explain as much as possible.

Comment: The most important point is trying different model orders. You need to get a feel for your data and the dynamic properties of your physical system. Do you know what linear model could represent the mechanisms of your system well in theory?